# Ensuring that floats are displayed in order of first reference

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, endfloat

There are many questions on this web site and elsewhere about ensuring that floats are displayed in the order in which they are placed in the source. What I want is different—I have all my floats at the end of my document and want to ensure that floats are displayed in the order in which they are *referenced* using `\ref` or `\autoref`. Using something like the `endfloat` package is not sufficient, because that requires me to make sure that the source order of the floats is the same as the reference order. It is easy to disrupt this ordering during editing.

It would suffice to have some sort of process that checked this for me automatically and required manual adjustments. Just as long as I don't have to go through and manually check again that Figure 13 is referenced in the output text before Figure 14.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commenting out the `\figuresatendtrue` the paper will compile as normally (with figures in place). Otherwise, they will go at the end in order of references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\iffiguresatend
\figuresatendtrue

\makeatletter
\iffiguresatend

\NewEnviron{figureatend}[2][\fps@figure]{%
  % #1 = placement options
  % #2 = key
  \global\expandafter\def\csname figureatend@store@#2\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\BODY\label{#2}}}

\providecommand\@namelet[1]{\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\figureatend@save{}
\def\figureatend@ref#1{%
    \g@addto@macro\figureatend@save{\figureatend@do{#1}}}
\def\figureatend@do#1{%
   \@ifundefined{figureatend@store@#1}{}{%
     \begin{figure}[p]\@nameuse{figureatend@store@#1}\end{figure}%
     \global\@namelet{figureatend@store@#1}\relax}}
\AtEndDocument{
  \ifx\figureatend@save\@empty\else
    \clearpage
    \figureatend@save
  \fi}

\pretocmd\@setref{\figureatend@ref{#3}}{}{}

\else

\newenvironment{figureatend}[2][\fps@figure]
  {\def\figureatendtemp{#2}\begin{figure}[#1]}
  {\label{\figureatendtemp}\end{figure}}

\fi


\begin{document}

\section{abc}\label{abc}

\ref{abc}--\ref{AAA}\lipsum[1] 

\begin{figureatend}{BBB}
\caption{Figure BBB}
\end{figureatend}

\begin{figureatend}{AAA}
\caption{Figure AAA}
\end{figureatend}

\ref{BBB}\ref{AAA}\autoref{AAA}

\end{document}
```

### Comments

The idea is to gather both the code for the figures and the references. Each command `\ref{label}` (and also `\autoref{label}` if `hyperref` is loaded) will update the internal variable `\figureatend@save` by adding `\figureatend@do{label}` to it. At the end we will execute this macro, see later.

Each `figureatend` environment takes as optional argument the usual positioning specifications; they will be ignored if we are in "endfigures" mode, but are handy for printing the document with figures in place. The mandatory argument is the label with which the figure will be referred to that *mustn't* be placed after `\caption`, contrary to the usual format. (It would be quite difficult to intercept a `\label` command in this environment and a label is necessary anyway.)

The contents of the environment becomes, in endfigures mode, the replacement text of the macro `\figureatend@store@label`, where `label` is the argument to the environment.

At the end of the run (with `\AtEndDocument`) we check whether the `\figureatend@save` macro is non empty and we execute it, that is we do

```
\figureatend@do{label}
```

for each `label` found during the LaTeX run (in the exact order of appearance). The macro `\figureatend@do{label}` just check if `\figureatend@store@label` is defined and, if so, it does

`\begin{figure}[p]`
<*contents of the* `figureatend` *environment labeled by* `label`>
`\label{label}\end{figure}`

if the macro is defined; otherwise it does nothing.

A couple of LaTeX runs are required, as usual.

If the `\figuresatend` line is commented out, the `figureatend` environment becomes just a `figure` environment and nothing is added to the `\ref` related macro `\@setref`.