# How to number floats by the first \ref

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

This question has been asked before but it has been quite a while since then, I wanted to check if there are newer/better ways to do this.

[number figures by order of appearence in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359823/number-figures-by-order-of-appearence-in-text)

[Ensuring that floats are displayed in order of first reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40824/ensuring-that-floats-are-displayed-in-order-of-first-reference)

I have an article with figures and tables dumped at the end of the doc as separate sections. I want to change the *numbering* of the floats according to the order in which they are first referred to in the text body (i.e. not the order that the \label{} appears in the doc).
I am not interested in the order that these floats appear because that is handled by Latex or the publisher but I need to make sure that figure 1 is the first figure mentioned in the text and Figure 2 is the second etc.

I need this because in the process of drafting the doc we add, remove, adjust the floats and the references to floats. The order of cross-ref to floats and the order that they are listed in their respective sections does not match, and then I need to manually read through the doc and check that each float appears in the same order as the refs to the float.

Comment: latex never re-orders floats of a given type so you need to arrange this yourself by moving the `figure` enviroment to by by the first `\ref`. (Your description of why you needed this was not too clear, it seems an unusual requirement?)

Comment: I know about that question, I did link to it above.

Comment: I know, that is how I found it but questions are archived forever by design and the site guidelines would be that duplicate does not "time out" so the fact that that is a few years old does not stop it being a duplicate. Having said that I did not vote to close as dup as I have gold badge and it would close instantly,  I just suggested it should be closed to give others a chance to decide

Comment: I dont think it is an unusual requirement. I think it is pretty standard for academic journals (and teams working an academic research) to want drafts where the floats are numbered according to the order in which they are referred to in the text. It can be done manually most of the time when there are not many floats but it becomes time consuming when, for example, refs to fig 1, 2 and 17 swap places between draft versions.

Comment: [The LaTeX Project](https://www.latex-project.org/) has a number of articles. I found two by a topic [float](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/2e-floats/) and this particular one  by Frank Mittelbach is worth reading: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2014-FMi-TUB-tb111mitt-float-placement.pdf).